# Are narcotics too dangerous?

Tags: recreational-drugs

Countries like China, Britain, and the U.S. have [banned  opium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition_of_drugs#US_prohibition_of_opium). The media is anti-narcotics and the [U.S. government spends billions](http://www.whitehouse.gov/ondcp/the-national-drug-control-budget-fy-2013-funding-highlights) of dollars enforcing these laws. We're told that narcotics are too dangerous.

But a quote on [adverse effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroin#Adverse_effects) says,

> Like most opioids, unadulterated heroin does not cause many long-term
>   complications other than dependence and constipation.

**Are narcotics really as dangerous** as the media and government would have you believe?

Comment: Are you asking only about opioids, or about all prohibited drugs?

Comment: Please define "harmful". You cite a source that tells you that some drugs cause dependence and constipation. Some people will view them as harms. Please bring a source claiming a specific harm you are doubtful about, otherwize, this question is both too broad and unclear.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed narcotics. *Harmful* as in the capacity to harm to the extent which justifies criminalizing narcotics and spending billions of dollars on the enforcement.

Comment: "harm to the extent which justifies criminalizing" is not a scientific question but a moral and principal one. Each person may have other criterias for what is criminal or not. That is why different countries have different laws, because their people or leaders hold different views on what constitutes harmful enough to justify criminalization.

Comment: "Are narcotics as harmful as we're told?" if you explain what *you* are told, then you might get clear answers.

Comment: @Bakuriu it's not that difficult to see that what we're told comes from the government and media. Google heroin if it helps.

Comment: @Eminem: We prefer there to be precise quotes from given sources, so we aren't all arguing against different definitions and different claims. It is reasonable to expect *some* claims from the media are going to be fanciful, and *some* claims are going to be accurate.

Comment: @Eminem I live in Italy, and I'm pretty sure different governments give different messages. He did not specify *any* claim in his question, only a vague and subjective opinion. If he asked, for example, "do narcotics cause (or greatly enhance the probability to get) schizophrenia?", that would be something people can answer objectively(up to current research and documentation at least).

Comment: Any analysis of the adverse effects of drugs (legal or otherwise) has to take into account the adverse effects of banning them as well. Otherwise you put millions of people in jail and ruin their lives to prevent them from taking drugs and ruining their lives. InRe: the current title, "too dangerous" for what?

Comment: One of the few hard narcotics that is legal, alcohol, causes 2.5 million deaths annually. Pretty good case for not making other hard drugs legal and readily available to everyone.

Answer (score 6):

*The term narcotic is [imprecise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcotic) and, in the US, has implications of "illicit". I am putting issues with the criminalisation of drugs aside, and I am focussing on heroin and cocaine in particular, as example narcotics.*

There is an additional long-term complication to these narcotics - death due to overdose.

According to a [CDC report](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/databriefs/db22.pdf) (key [table](ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Publications/Data_Briefs/db022/fig02.xls)), there were over 7.476 deaths due to cocaine overdose and 2,090 deaths due to heroin overdose in the United States in 2006.

While those numbers might include (a) double-counting if both drugs were involved, (b) deliberate suicides and (c) deaths that would not have occurred had the drug been decriminalised - e.g due to impurities, (d) deaths that would not have occurred if the drugs had been consumed within the purview of a medical facility, it is clear that the statement that there are no serious complications to narcotics is inaccurate.

Comment: I've heard that complications may include theft etc. (to support the habit), loss or replacement of socially-useful/acceptable motivations, etc.

Comment: I lump those issues in with factors associated with criminalisation - i.e. not necessarily associated with the drug itself, so much as associated with dependence on an illicit drug. If you think there is more involved than that, I'd love to see that as an answer.

Comment: The OP opens with references to prohibition: so I thought he was asking for evidence of whether that prohibition is justified. He cited a Wikipedia sentence which says that there are "no long-term complications" for the individual, which I find a bit dubious; but IMO the larger or more compelling "complication", which you shouldn't ignore if you're questioning prohibition, is social. Referencing the Opium wars is relevant because it explains why prohibition came about, and because it gives an otherwise unavailable insight into its effect in a society which hadn't (yet) enacted prohibition.

Comment: Some deaths due to overdose may be deliberate suicide [ref](http://archive.org/stream/39002055095831.med.yale.edu#page/42/mode/2up/search/suicide).

Comment: @ChrisW: The OP is changing the question. I am addressing the only notable claim that has been made so far. I certainly agree there are other issues which aren't the drug, per se, but the illegality of the drug. Also, I agree that some deaths may due to suicide - see my point labelled "(b)". For this reason, stopping ODs may not stop all 9,500 deaths per year.

Comment: FYI I was wondering how many "2,090 deaths" from heroin is, given the size of the population of the USA: it contrasts with 60,000 deaths from transport accidents; 35,000 suicides by firearm; 25,000 deaths from alcohol (excluding accidents and homicides). There are laws which regulate the use of cars, guns, and alcohol, however those laws aren't prohibitive.

Comment: You should probably count a non-trivial number of the ODs against the drug war as well: when people can't get supplies of reliable purity or good advice on what doses represent a risk they are going to make more mistakes.

Comment: @ChrisW: These are good questions. Cars have practical value, meaning they may save more lives than they kill. I'm not going to touch the same question about firearms. If alcohol was invented today, I suspect it would be outlawed. But, I am not arguing for or against prohibition. I am arguing that narcotics are more dangerous than the quoted claim suggests.

Comment: @dmckee: Agreed. I tried to cover that by my point labelled "(c)". The killer question is "Would the total deaths rise or fall if heroin were to be be decriminalised?" I am not attempting to address that here.

Comment: Death ratios only make sense when you know the over-all size of the population using them. I think more people in the US drive cars and more often than use heroin.

Answer (score 3):

IMO we should take it for granted that opium (and perhaps cocaine) has been found to be desirable by at least some of the people who have tried it, resulting in addiction or at least repeated use, and that it is fairly safe or well-tolerated (in that, at the least, users tend not to die of it, at least not immediately).

I think that the main argument against (and the argument in favour of making them illegal) is the cost to society.

Quoting from the [Opium article in the Encyclopedia Brittanica of 1911](http://archive.org/stream/encyclopdiabri20chis#page/130/mode/2up):

> The Chinese government regardng the use of opium as one of the most acute moral and economic questions which as a nation they have to face, representing a loss to the country of 856,250,000 taels, decided in 1906 to put an end to the drug within 10 years

and

> In October of the same year, the American government in the Philippines, having to deal with the opium trade, ...

and

> At this meeting it was resolved that it was the duty of the respective governments to prevent the export of opium to any countries prohibiting its importation

and

> The difficulties of the task undertaken by the Chinese government to eradicate a national and popular vice, in a country whose population is generally estimated at 400,000,000, are increased by the fact that opium has been indulged in by all classes of society, that opium has been the principal if not the only national stimulant; that it must involve a considerable loss of revenue, etc.

On [page 136](http://archive.org/stream/encyclopdiabri20chis#page/136/mode/2up) of the same source,

> In 1906 is was estimated that 13,455,699 of Chinese smoked opium, or 27% of adult males; but during 1908-1910 the consumption of opium is believed to have diminished by about one third.

The result was the [International Opium Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Opium_Convention):

> The International Opium Convention, signed at The Hague on January 23, 1912 during the First International Opium Conference, was the first international drug control treaty. It was registered in League of Nations Treaty Series on January 23, 1922.

The text of that convention is easy to find; <strike>but I haven't found (except for the Encyclopedia Britannica article mentioned above) a statement of what motivated that agreement.</strike> and here is the [Report of the International opium commission, Shanghai, China, February 1 to February 26, 1909](http://archive.org/details/cu31924032583225) (620 pages) which preceded and motivated that agreement. However it seems that commission is more about how to stop the trade: for example the [introduction on page 9](http://archive.org/stream/cu31924032583225#page/n15/mode/2up) states as a given that it's a harmful "bane" (which may be why they called that Commission to discuss it), and the [message from the President of the United States](http://archive.org/stream/cu31924032583225#page/n531/mode/2up) is headed "Opium problem", as if the fact that it was problem was common knowledge.

Wikipedia's article about [Hampden Coit DuBose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampden_Coit_DuBose) says,

> As a witness of the destructive problems of opium addiction in China, he was moved to join with other likeminded missionaries and Christian medical workers to form the Anti-Opium League in China. DuBose was its first president. In 1899 the League published a seminal book called Opinions of Over 100 Physicians on the Use of Opium in China. The book illustrated the purpose of the league and published facts about the opium abuse crisis that ultimately influenced public opinion against the trade. DuBose eventually gained the support of U.S. President Theodore Roosevelt, the U.S. Congress, and the International Opium Commission. In 1906 the League achieved success when the British Parliament declared that the trade was "morally indefensible." DuBose circulated a petition signed by over a thousand missionaries in China and it was presented to the Guangxu Emperor. In turn the Emperor issued an imperial edict, following verbatim the petition Dubose had drafted, which prohibited the trade and abuse of opium.
>
> In a letter to U.S. Senator John McLaurin he called upon the U.S. to own its responsibility for the opium trade, in that, along with Great Britain it had profited at the expense of the Chinese. He asserted:
>
> “ …opium has no judicious use…save as administered by a physician[1]  ”

His use of the term "judicious" was I guess because of its addictive properties. For example, Wikipedia's [Cocaine dependence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocaine_dependence) article says,

> Cocaine addiction continues to be the most difficult to manage behind heroin, and according to some scientists, addiction to cocaine may be almost impossible to stop.[23][24]

Assuming that [Opinions of over 100 physicians on the use of opium in China (1899)](http://archive.org/details/39002055095831.med.yale.edu) was as influential as stated, here are some extracts from it. The first chapter is about the "moral, physical, and social" effects.

Page v. Introduction:

> The slaves of the habit have their faces shrunken and dark. They become old, infirm, and incapacitated before their time, and all finances are exhausted. This condition is pitiable but it is not the worst -- for those who hold office on their part become greedy and grasping, those who are soldiers become nerveless, and the number of depraved population is increased steadily, while the wealth of the country steadily decreases.

Page 2:

> This depends largely on a man's means; if he can afford to eat well and plentifully, opium has not the same deleterious effect on the body as when he is badly off for food; he may not lose flesh, but he loses color and powers of resistance. The moral and social effects can never be good, but the degree of badness depends very largely on circumstances -- the temptations a man is led into, either of place or to obtain the drug, the length of time taken and the amount of the drug used each day.